# Trouble with mySQL Database's foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I am working on a database for my class. It is to be used with a website, and has to keep track of users and their passwords, conferences and their events, and presenters.

Using the mySQL workbench, I created an ERR Diagram, and linked all the tables together, having the conferenceID in the event table match to the conferenceID in the conference table and so on, trying to get the foreign keys to work.

When trying to construct the database, the compiler said:

> "#1005 - Can't create table 'mydb'.'events' (errno:150 "foreign key constraint is incorectly formed")"

I would like to know what went wrong with my foreign keys and how I should fix them.

What is supposed to be linked:

- userID in 'user' table & userID in 'userEvents' table
- sigGroup1-5 in 'user & sigID in 'SIGS'
- event1-20 in 'userEvents' table & eventsID in 'events' table
- presenterID in 'presenter' table & presenterID in 'events' table
- confrenceID in 'confrence' table & confrenceID in 'events' table
- roomID in 'room' table & roomID in 'events' table
- tag1-5 in 'events' table & tagsID in 'tags' table
- venueID in 'confrence' table & venueID in 'room' table
- confrenceID in 'presenter' table & confrenceID in 'confrence' table

I can post the ERR diagram if need be.

Thanks in advance for any help. the FK's have always been tricky for me.

Here is my sql code. Everything should be okay except the FK's.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`tags`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`tags` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`tags` (
  `tagsID` INT NOT NULL,
  `Tags` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tagsID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`confrence`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`confrence` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`confrence` (
  `confrenceID` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `desc` VARCHAR(200) NULL,
  `venue` VARCHAR(75) NOT NULL,
  `venueID` INT NOT NULL,
  `googleLink` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`confrenceID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`room`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`room` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`room` (
  `roomID` INT NOT NULL,
  `venueID` INT NOT NULL,
  `roomNumber` INT NOT NULL,
  `roomName` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `capacity` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`roomID`),
  INDEX `fk_room_confrence_idx` (`venueID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_room_confrence`
    FOREIGN KEY (`venueID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`confrence` (`confrenceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`presenter`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`presenter` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`presenter` (
  `presenterID` INT NOT NULL,
  `confrenceID` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `link` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  `events_eventsID` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`presenterID`),
  INDEX `fk_presenter_confrence_idx` (`confrenceID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_presenter_confrence`
    FOREIGN KEY (`confrenceID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`confrence` (`confrenceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`events`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`events` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`events` (
  `eventsID` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `presenterID` INT NOT NULL,
  `startTime` INT NOT NULL,
  `endTime` INT NOT NULL,
  `desc` VARCHAR(250) NULL,
  `tag1` INT NULL,
  `tag2` INT NULL,
  `tag3` INT NULL,
  `tag4` INT NULL,
  `tag5` INT NULL,
  `roomID` INT NULL,
  `confrenceID` INT NULL,
  `date` DATE NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`eventsID`),
  INDEX `fk_events_tags_idx` (`tag1` ASC, `tag2` ASC, `tag3` ASC, `tag4` ASC, `tag5` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_events_confrence_idx` (`confrenceID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_events_room_idx` (`roomID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_events_presenter_idx` (`presenterID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events_tags`
    FOREIGN KEY (`tag1` , `tag2` , `tag3` , `tag4` , `tag5`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`tags` (`tagsID` , `tagsID` , `tagsID` , `tagsID` ,  `tagsID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT `fk_events_confrence`
    FOREIGN KEY (`confrenceID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`confrence` (`confrenceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events_room`
    FOREIGN KEY (`roomID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`room` (`roomID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_events_presenter`
    FOREIGN KEY (`presenterID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`presenter` (`presenterID`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`userEvents`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`userEvents` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`userEvents` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL,
  `event1` INT NULL,
  `event2` INT NULL,
  `event3` INT NULL,
  `event4` INT NULL,
  `event5` INT NULL,
  `event6` INT NULL,
  `event7` INT NULL,
  `event8` INT NULL,
  `event9` INT NULL,
  `event10` INT NULL,
  `event11` INT NULL,
  `event12` INT NULL,
  `event13` INT NULL,
  `event14` INT NULL,
  `event15` INT NULL,
  `event16` INT NULL,
  `event17` INT NULL,
  `event18` INT NULL,
  `event19` INT NULL,
  `event20` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  INDEX `fk_userEvents_events_idx` (`event1` ASC, `event2` ASC, `event3` ASC, `event4` ASC, `event5` ASC, `event6` ASC, `event7` ASC, `event8` ASC, `event9` ASC, `event10` ASC, `event11` ASC, `event12` ASC, `event13` ASC, `event14` ASC, `event15` ASC, `event16` ASC, `event17` ASC, `event18` ASC, `event19` ASC, `event20` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_userEvents_events`
    FOREIGN KEY (`event1` , `event2` , `event3` , `event4` , `event5` , `event6` , `event7` , `event8` , `event9` , `event10` , `event11` , `event12` , `event13` , `event14` , `event15` , `event16` , `event17` , `event18` , `event19` , `event20`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`events` (`eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID` , `eventsID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`SIGS`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`SIGS` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`SIGS` (
  `sigID` INT NOT NULL,
  `sigName` VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sigID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mydb`.`user` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`user` (
  `userID` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `type` INT NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  `sigGroup1` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup1Admin` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup2` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup2Admin` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup3` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup3Admin` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup4` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup4Admin` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup5` INT NULL,
  `sigGroup5Admin` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userID`),
  INDEX `fk_user_SIGS_idx` (`sigGroup1` ASC, `sigGroup2` ASC, `sigGroup3` ASC, `sigGroup4` ASC, `sigGroup5` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_userEvents`
    FOREIGN KEY (`userID`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`userEvents` (`userID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_user_SIGS`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sigGroup1` , `sigGroup2` , `sigGroup3` , `sigGroup4` , `sigGroup5`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`SIGS` (`sigID` , `sigID` , `sigID` , `sigID` , `sigID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Data for table `mydb`.`user`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
START TRANSACTION;
USE `mydb`;
INSERT INTO `mydb`.`user` (`userID`, `username`, `type`, `password`, `sigGroup1`, `sigGroup1Admin`, `sigGroup2`, `sigGroup2Admin`, `sigGroup3`, `sigGroup3Admin`, `sigGroup4`, `sigGroup4Admin`, `sigGroup5`, `sigGroup5Admin`)     VALUES (1, 'admin', 1, 'admin', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: you don't hav a foreign key FOREIGN KEY (`tag1` , `tag2` , `tag3` , `tag4` , `tag5`) but 5 foreign keys  FOREIGN KEY (`tag1`) ...

Comment: And you don't want to be doing it that way anyhow.  You need an events to tags table.  Same with anything where you've got a number in the name because you've got "some" of them.  They belong in a table.

Comment: I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: Thank you @LoztInSpace, adding the events to tags table and the like fixed the problem. The database is working and the site is running fine. I don't know why I thought the numbered way would work.